# SharePoint 2007 Calendar - Remove Time

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, sharepoint-designer

Does anyone know how to remove the time from a SharePoint 2007 Calendar month view?

I could do this using some jQuery but would like to know if it is possible via configuration?

Cheers